# What brand of 3D printing materials is the most famous/popular?

Tags: filament, material

I am new to 3D printing and have read there is a fair bit of knowledge required to use the right product for printing.

In search for a good quality brand to start with, what is the most used filament based on sale volume worldwide?

Comment: A potentially more appropriate question for the SE network might be **What effects filament quality?**, then track down how a particular supplier processes the material.